# Bash: output line count from wc in human readable format

Tags: macos, bash, wc

Is that possible? Doing *wc* the straight forward way I have to spend some mental energy to see that the file contains more than 40 million lines:

```
$ wc -l 20150210.txt 
    45614736 20150210.txt
```

I searched around and *numfmt* showed up, but that is evidently not available on OSX (nor on *brew*). So is there a simple way to do this on OSX? Thanks.

Comment: Does `printf "%'d\n" 45614736` do what you want on OS X? (I don't know how portable that format string is.)

Comment: Note `gnumfmt` should be available throgh `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have [POSIX printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) you can use the `%'d`:

```
printf "%'d\n" $(wc -l < file )
```

From [`man printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **'**
>
> For decimal conversion (i, d, u, f, F, g, G) the output is to be
>   grouped with thousands' grouping characters if the locale information
>   indicates any. Note that many versions of gcc(1) cannot parse this
>   option and will issue a warning. SUSv2 does not include %'F

#### Test

```
$ seq 100000 > a
$ printf "%'d\n" $(wc -l <a )
100,000
```

Note also the trick `wc -l < file` to get the number without the file name.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do `$printf "%'d\n" 45614736` i get the output `45614736` with no formatting. Strange?

Comment: The output from `%'d` is locale-dependent. What is the output of `locale | grep LC_NUMERIC`?

Comment: Ah, it says `LC_NUMERIC="C"`

Comment: I did `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`. Now it works. Thanks